# Darken CSS background image?

Tags: html, css

Should be a fairly simple question. In my website I do this:

```
#landing-wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background:url('landingpagepic.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    height:350px;
}
```

What I'd like to do is make the background image darker. Since I have UI elements inside this DIV I don't think I can really place another div over it to darken it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 455, accepted):

You can use the [CSS3 Linear Gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) property along with your background-image like this:

```
#landing-wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('landingpagepic.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    height:350px;
}
```

Here's a demo:

```css
#landing-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-position: center top;
  height: 350px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing-wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor ismet.</div>
```

Comment: This does not work in IE9. Any way around that?

Comment: @BrechtMachiels I think the best workaround for IE is to use transparent image

Comment: @john1717 Let's be real... the best workaround for IE is probably to not use IE

Comment: It still works under `background-image` if you are setting other background properties in different places i.e. `background-size`/`background-repeat` `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('http://placehold.it/350x150');`

Comment: Thanks!!! is there also a way to rotate the image?

Comment: Why use a background image ? Just don't use a linear gradient and instead just give it a color of black and adjust the opacity as needed

Comment: @Ambleu I recommend you search for or ask a new question for that info.

Comment: Agreed with @john1717, It's time to stop supporting IE altogether, especially since Microsoft Edge is now based on Chromium.

Comment: I tried this method with both `background` and `background-image`, and was left with a white background in both scenarios, instead of a darkened background image. Thoughts?