# How to darken a CSS background image?

Tags: html, css

I am pulling my hair out over this. I have tried literally everything I have found and at this point I'm guessing I must just be making some kind of mistake. I am trying to darken the background image so that it is not quite as saturated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body id="home">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="#">Bearbeard Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Eretikas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="slogan">THE HERETIC SWORD</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
#home {
  background-image: url(file:///Volumes/Animus/Jon/Dropbox/website/hellcity.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#slogan {
  color: #FFFAF0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This gives me a background that completely covers the page. But I want to darken it (without hovering, or clicking). Everything I have tried has NOT achieved any darkening whatsoever (I've tried fake-gradients, `reba` stuff, etc.), and somehow gets in the way of `<div id="slogan">` and `<nav>`, pushing them all over the place.

Is my formatting just totally incorrect?

Comment: Why not modify the picture `hellcity.jpg` to be darker?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to do it via CSS so that I don't have to edit photos in the future (as opposed to just using them as they come and using the tools in my utility belt to do it for me).

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535392/how-to-decrease-image-brightness-in-css) on how to decrease brightness, does that help? I would recommend using the `filter: brightness` answer.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- I've actually tried that and it strangely does nothing, which is part of why I'm so confused.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using/supporting? Maybe the browser you're in doesn't support 'filter' at all.

Comment: @BSMP I'm in the most recent Safari which is listed as supporting -webkit-filter. Not sure why it wasn't making any noticeable changes, though.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
#home {
   background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('file:///Volumes/Animus/Jon/Dropbox/website/hellcity.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[This should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621513/darken-css-background-image)

Comment: So, I have no idea why... But this did it.

I tried this before, written with the rgba portions on their own lines (or maybe I only had one rgba instead of both?).

edit: So, I don't know how to show you what I was doing before to determine why this is working now when it didn't work before. :'/

Regardless, could you explain why this darkens the entire background when all of the other methods shown (and in other answers for this SAME question) would only darken the contents of <nav>?

Comment: I think your tags were not formatted properly and the before and hover:body elements were bleeding over into the nav's markup.  I can't know without you going back a few steps and pasting the source here to confirm.

Comment: just to make sure I understand you, you're suggesting that I was possibly not closing or opening the () or {} correctly, leading to this section of instructions eating the ones that follow? This very well may be totally correct.

Comment: well... more like the <> tags, but yes  - something as little as "</nav"  would break it and cause your nav bar to be black too

Comment: The joys of starting out. Well, thank you again, I really appreciate the input.

Comment: No idea why but this doesn't seem to work at all for me in either Chrome or Safari.
Standard html starter layout with empty html and body tags and the following css:
`html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('LarryPhone.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: @jwhubert91 when you inspect element are any of those elements greyed out because another property is overwriting them?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the background on `body` tag, and add a darken layer with pseudo content with `rgba()` + `alpha`, then wrap all the content into a `div` and set it to `position:relative`, to make it stays on top.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
body:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    transition: background .5s;
}
body:hover:before {
    /*for demo, move this line up if you want to darken it as default*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
div {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.tile:hover{
    background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

This worked for me to adjust ONLY the background image on a div.

The background-color can be adjusted to make the image more or less bright.

Comment: Found this useful for a situation where modifying HTML was not practical.

Answer (score 2):

**Using filter property**

Just use,

```
filter: brightness(50%);
```

for the image to lower the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

create a container div that fits 100% of #home then:

```
#container {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

the 0.5 = 50% opacity...

it will have the effect of darkening the background image

Comment: This is one of the methods I've tried. What winds up happening is it darkens the nav/ul elements instead of the background.

Comment: if you add container after body, BEFORE you do the header then there is no way that it could darkern those, unless you use something  like z-index

Comment: @theblackveil - Can you go ahead and add all of the methods you've tried already to your question?

Answer (score 1):

First order of business:
   You do not need id or class on body element

and second see the code below.

```css
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(http://adityamehta.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Sky-Blue-Sky.jpg);
}

nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#slogan {
  color: #FFFAF0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Bearbeard Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Eretikas</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Custom</a><li>
        </ul>

        <div id="slogan">THE HERETIC SWORD</div>
     </nav>
   </body>
```

Original image thanks to google :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I absolutely understand your first point, it was something I did in an attempt to try new things. - -; Thank you, though, I wasn't positive about it. The second point, I'm not sure I follow? What should not be inside body? I'm just trying make sure I do things right moving forward.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind expanding on why <header></header> shouldn't be inside body? I have a <head></head> section that is NOT inside the body. The <header></header> segment came from a png of "Beautiful HTML," and my thought was that it was intended to separate the nav-contents from the rest of the page. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Sorry my bad, <header></header> is html5 and is allowed inside a body, and I did get it confused with `<head></head>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `background-blend-mode` property and set it to darken. It would look like this

```
background-blend-mode:darken;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add position relative to your #home, then the following to your CSS:

```
#home::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

(0.5 could changed depending on how dark you would like to image to be.)

Then do a z-index to bring the other content above the overlay:

```
#home * {
  z-index: 10; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#home {
   background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ),url('file:///Volumes/Animus/Jon/Dropbox/website/hellcity.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation.

Comment: Okay, but it is true, no ?

Comment: It's hard to say without an explanation. You "can" do *anything* with CSS but will it do *what you want* or *what OP asks*?